# Adding Post Thumbnail to Metro Pro Theme

Tags: images

I am trying to add a post thumbnail so that when users land on my homepage queenmypawn.com, they see an image to the right of the text, like in the website https://totalreporter.com/.

Currently my website doesn't do this. I tried using this guide: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-featured-image-or-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress/. I added a featured image and the php code, but I am confused at this very stage:

> To display featured images in your theme, you need to edit your templates and add this line of code where you want to display the featured image:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

> The files you add the above code in will vary based on your theme. You will want to add the code inside your post loop.

Which types of files are those?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://studiopress.community/topic/removing-featured-image-from-top-of-posts-only/) on the StudioPress forums mentions going to the Theme Settings in Genesis.

Inside the Content Archives, click the checkbox that says "Display the featured image?".

On doing so, the featured image pops up.